# Function returning None type value

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, nonetype

Im having a problem with this funcion (menu) in my code, its returning None, but when I print the value of the input(option) it prints normally.follow the whole code:

## Menu File

```
class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def menu(self):
        print("\n|1|")
        print('Play Game\n')
        print("-=" * 30)
        print("\n|2|")
        print('Quit\n')
        option = int(input('Digit 1 to play the game \n\t\tor \nDigit 2 to quit the game'))
        print(option)
        return option
```

## Game File

```
import menu


menu = menu.Menu()


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def numberofcards(self, value=0):
        if value > 4 and value < 30 and value % 2 == 0:
            return value
        else:
            print("""Please enter a valid number of cards to continue.The 
number should be
greater than four, less than thirty and should be an even number""")
            menu.menu()
```

## Main File

```
import game
import menu

menu = menu.Menu()
game = game.Game()

a = game.numberofcards(27)
print(a)
```

Comment: `int` never returns `None`, so you're missing something here. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your code works fine for me running `Python 2.7` in IDLE. What environment are you running it in?

Comment: Im running it on Pyhton 3.6 on IDLE.I will provide the whole code then(the code is divided in some files...Thats why i had to import them...

Comment: Oh yeah, and of course im running the main file, although im pretty sure the problem is in the menu file

Comment: Your `else` block doesn't return anything so `game.numberofcards(27)` returns None